# Flutter SQFLite can't assign Future Int to int

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I need to extract the number of records for SQFlite database table.

I need to assign the number of records from DB to the myCount int field.

```
int myCount = 0;
```

The following code extracts the number of records from DB.

```
Future<int?> countRecords() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(${Fields.id}) FROM $Table');
    final list = result.map((json) => Record.fromJson(json)).toList();
    if(list.isNotEmpty) return list.length; else throw Exception('Empty List');
  }
```

I need to use the above code below:

```
Future<int?> countDBRecords() async {
    return myCount = (await DB.instance.countDBRecords())!;
}
```

My Issue: I cannot assign Future int to int.

```
 int countRecordsTotal(){
    myCount = countDBRecords(); -> this line is the issue.
    return myCount;
}
```

Could you please suggest how to extract the number of records from DB and assign to a variable.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not something related to SQFlite.
You need to use `await` as long as you're using asynchronous function.
This is the solution to you're problem.

```
Future<int> countRecordsTotal() async {
        myCount = (await countDBRecords())!; //! is for null check
        return myCount;
    }
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.
Also you should learn about asynchronous Dart code, if you don't know much about it.

Comment: Hello. Sorry, this is incorrect answer b/c using await implies that it is Future. I need the Future to become int. I have: Future<int?> countDBRecords() and int countRecordsTotal(). I need to use Future as int variable. How would I achieve this? Thank You

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that `countDBRecords()` returns a `Future<int?>` and so you can't assign the `Future` object to the `int` variable.

To get the int value itself, add the `await` keyword before the `countDBRecords()` function call.

Like this:

```dart
Future<int?> countRecordsTotal() async{
    myCount = await countDBRecords(); 
    return myCount;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry, this is incorrect answer b/c using await implies that it is Future. I need the Future to become int. I have: Future<int?> countDBRecords() and int countRecordsTotal(). I need to use Future as int variable. How would I achieve this? Thank You

Comment: Hello @DktPhl2018, `countDBRecords()` *is* a Future. The way to get the `int` value out is using `await` or `.then`. 

Can you explain why you want it as an int? Also please post the part of the code where you use `countRecordsTotal()`.

Comment: All the code I have is already posted above. I need to extract the number of records from the database to determine how many records DB has after app restart. That's why I need Future to int.

Comment: Can you post where you are trying to extract the number of records after the app restart so I can understand the difficulty with using a Future and give a different solution if needed?

Comment: Probably not b/c I have too much code. My goal is: New records added after app restart should not overwrite existing records. The idea is very simple. There is one TextField. Clicking Save adds new record and creates a list and saves the new record in the DB. Once you stopped adding new items, you do app restart, and then you continue to add new records. On app restart, the visual list indexes become zero. So, you need to extract DB records to get the correct records count.